# Solution to a linear system with a circulant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, recursion

I'm trying to find the solution to the following recursion, but my attempts to inductively find it haven't been fruitful. Any ideas that may help?

$x_1 = a_1 + \dfrac{x_n}{4}+ \dfrac{x_2}{4}$

$x_2 = a_2 + \dfrac{x_1}{4}+ \dfrac{x_3}{4}$

$\vdots$

$x_{n-1} = a_{n-1} + \dfrac{x_{n-2}}{4}+ \dfrac{x_n}{4}$

$x_n = a_n + \dfrac{x_{n-1}}{4}+ \dfrac{x_1}{4}$

Comment: This is not really recursion: it's a linear system with a circulant matrix. The inverse matrix does not seem nice. See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+(1%2F4)+%5B%5B4,-1,0,0,-1%5D,%5B-1,4,-1,0,0%5D,%5B0,-1,4,-1,0%5D,%5B0,0,-1,4,-1%5D,%5B-1,0,0,-1,4%5D%5D).

Comment: Circulant matrices are diagonalized by the discrete Fourier basis. So change basis to the discrete Fourier basis and the linear system will become diagonal. In a computer implementation you can use the FFT to solve the system efficiently.